# How to create android app for control pc mouse

Tags: java, android, udp, remote-access

I'm interested to create android application that have all the functionality of PC mouse,keyboard and it can control the connected PC via wifi but I have little knowledge about this and I don't know where to start.I like to know are there are any protocol to do this,are there are any open source code project that i can download?

Comment: Flagging for: *Questions asking us to recommend or find a book, tool, software library, tutorial or other off-site resource are off-topic for Stack Overflow*

Answer (score 3):

You should understand that this is not just Android application.

This is a pair of applications:

- Computer - server
- Android - client

And you get to decide how they will communicate. You can write your server application on C++, which will receive data via BlueTooth with Android and call the system API.

Comment: any way do this using wifi?

Comment: Of course. Then you need to look up a server (computer) on your network.

Comment: I recommend to start making chat. This is the most simple client-server interaction. And then, depending on the message to produce manipulation on a computer.